# To take only the number in Size in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to identify which file is contributing more in my directory structure. For this I am doing the following steps manually

Example: `du -sh * [0-9]G` this will give me all the folders inside which are having GB size.

```
2.0G images
3.7G files
8.9G audio
```

I want my variable to take only the highest sized directory size like 8.9, how can i do this in awk or grep

Comment: pipe to `sort` and then `tail -1` (or `head -1`).

Comment: Just bear in mind if you do that, you'll ignore directories that are 1T :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might change this a bit to:

```
du -sk .??* * | sort -rn | head -1
```

The interesting difference is the `.??* *` which will catch those pesky "hidden" directories.  Chief among those offenders is `.cache`.

Comment: I take this approach normally, because I don't like "losing" 999m directories, or even 1T directories ;). And if the formatting really bothers me,  it's easy enough to divide by 1024 a few times :)

Answer (score 0):

```
du -sh * | cut -f 1 | grep G | sort -g | tail -1
```

using `du` as you do

cut the first field

grep for keeping only those which are in G

sort numerically `-g`

get the last one (bigger)